# How to feed SHGetKnownFolderPath output to CopyFile in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, casting

I want to get `FOLDERID_ProgramFiles` by `SHGetKnownFolderPath` and copy current running file to it by this code:

```
char ModuleFileName[24];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, ModuleFileName, MAX_PATH) ;

PWSTR path = NULL;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_ProgramFiles,0,NULL,&path);

CopyFile(ModuleFileName,path,FALSE);
```

But i had no lock because , `PWSTR` is a `wchar_t*` and `CopyFile` needs `const char*` , I have tried to put star before `Path` and convert it by using `wcstombs` function but no lock!

How can i fix it?

PS: I've got this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘PWSTR {aka wchar_t*}’ to ‘LPCSTR {aka const char*}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘WINBOOL CopyFileA(LPCSTR, LPCSTR, WINBOOL)’
```

And i should mention I'am using `Mingw g++` compiler so printing out these variable is a bit challenging by using `wprintf(L"%ls\n",[STR] );` and i get a lot of bad chars in output.

Comment: Change `CopyFile` to `CopyFileW`  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes for an explanation.  Suggest you conciser using Unicode as the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the ANSI version of `CopyFile()` and passing it a Unicode string in the second parameter.  That is why you are getting a compiler error.  Use the Unicode version of `GetModuleFileName()` and `CopyFile()` instead.

Also, your `ModuleFileName` is only 24 `char`s in size, but you are telling `GetModuleFileNameW()` that it is `MAX_PATH` (260) chars in size.

Also, `CopyFile()` expects file paths, not folder paths. You need to extract the filename from `ModuleFileName` and append it to the end of `path` when passing it to the 2nd parameter.

Try something more like this:

```c
WCHAR ModuleFileName[MAX_PATH] = {};
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, ModuleFileName, MAX_PATH);

PWSTR path = NULL;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_ProgramFiles, 0, NULL, &path);

WCHAR NewFileName[MAX_PATH] = {};
PathCombineW(NewFileName, path, PathFindFileNameW(ModuleFileName));

CoTaskMemFree(path);

CopyFileW(ModuleFileName, NewFileName, FALSE);
```

There are other alternatives to `PathCombine()`, eg:

```c
WCHAR NewFileName[PATHCCH_MAX_CCH] = {};
PathCchCombine(NewFileName, PATHCCH_MAX_CCH, path, PathFindFileNameW(ModuleFileName));
// use NewFileName as needed...
```

```c
PWSTR NewFileName = NULL;
PathAllocCombine(path, PathFindFileNameW(ModuleFileName), 0, &NewFileName);
// use NewFileName as needed...
LocalFree(NewFileName);
```

```cpp
#include <string>
std::wstring NewFileName(path);
if (NewFileName.back() != L'\\')
    NewFileName += L'\\';
NewFileName += PathFindFileNameW(ModuleFileName);
// use NewFileName as needed...
```

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
std::wstring NewFileName = (std::filesystem::path(path) / PathFindFileNameW(ModuleFileName)).wstring();
// use NewFileName as needed...
```

Comment: Thank you sir , I can't find **pathcch.h** linker library , do you know by any chance what linker should i use for this library, i get **undefined reference to `_imp__PathAllocCombine@16'**

Comment: @malloc [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathalloccombine), you need `Pathcch.lib`. And there are other path combination functions available (`Path(Cch)Combine()`, `Path(Cch)Append()`, etc)

Comment: I've read that before, and i search that symbol in all libraries in Mingw compiler and nothing came up, no libraries contain that symbol. I guess i should change the **PathAllocCombine**

Comment: @malloc is your compiler had `pathcch.h`, it should have `pathcch.lib`, too. Worse case, you can always generate a new `.lib` from the `.dll` directly, or use `GetProcAddress()` to load the function dynamically

Comment: Yes it have pathcch.h but no pathcch.lib , Okey let me see what i can do, thanks again.

Comment: I've been searching for pathcch.lib on the internet or pathcch.a for Mingw compiler and I've no luck so i've decided to combine those(File path +file name) by casting them to string but i couldn't. Would you help me on this , sir, because i don't know what to do. Thanks.

Comment: @malloc you need to use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`, eg: `wstring NewFileName(path); if (NewFileName.back() != L'\\') { NewFileName += L'\\'; } NewFileName += PathFindFileNameW(ModuleFileName); CopyFileW(ModuleFileName, NewFileName.c_str(), FALSE);`

Comment: Thank you sir, I print out the **NewFileName** , it remove the last char of the address and replace it with  \\ , for example it output **C:\Program File(X86\\myprogram.exe** with this  `warning: character constant too long for its type
  NewFileName += L'  \\'`

Comment: I did remove -1 and address get corrected , but it still does not copy file to that location.

Comment: It is because spaces in address, i change the folder to FOLDERID_Desktop , and it copied!

Comment: Would you Please change the PathAllocCombine part of your answer with you newly added code so i can accept it, Thanks.

Comment: @malloc The code I gave you does not truncate any characters, only adds characters. If you are getting truncation, you did something wrong when you applied the code to your project. But in any case, you really should use path management functions instead of building the paths manually. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes i know what you are saying, but with some cross compilation issues and Mingw compiler and restriction in it , I found this solution handy .Thank you sir for your time .

Comment: @RemyLebeau Interesting question for you... why would you use call so many functions when you can get this folder path from the ENV variable?

Comment: @Mecanik environment variables can be messed with, so may not be what you expect. Using the Win32 API functions is more accurate

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, but I doubt a regular user has any idea how to alter the PEB to achieve that. I was just curious on why you would use so many API's and link 2 extra libs for such simple purpose.

Comment: @Mecanik messing with environment variables doesnt require altering the PEB. In any case, how would you propose building a new path string using just an environment variable? You would still have to query the calling process's path and extract its file name, query the OS/environment for the target path, and append the file name to it. Whether you use API functions for that, or just use plain string operations, doesn't really matter. It is still a multi-step operation

Comment: @RemyLebeau For some reason, I did not get the notification. I have been doing this for a long time now. So with that being said... here's how to make a full path for anything inside your current directory: Peb()->ProcessParameters->CurrentDirectory.DosPath.Buffer and wcscat_s. Boom, done. No extra libs or external functions called. Same can be done for ENV vars as well, since they are all passed into the PEB.

Comment: @Mecanik *Proper* path handling is more complex than that. You are not checking if the directory path ends with ```\``` or not before appending to it. And you are not checking if the final length of the path + filename will fit in the target buffer. Microsoft and C++ both offer safer APIs for handling paths for a reason. In any case, you shouldn't be accessing the `PEB` directly to get the `CurrentDirectory`, use `GetCurrentDirectory()` instead. Not to mention, the OP didn't ask to use the `CurrentDirectory` to begin with, they asked for the `ProgramFiles` folder instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's just an example, and my point was that you do not need extra libraries for simple tasks, including program files folder. Also, GetCurrentDirectory() just calls RtlGetCurrentDirectory_U() which inside is just ->ProcessParameters->CurrentDirectory with a few checks. At the end of the day the OP can choose to do whatever, but I wouldn't link 2 libraries for this simple purpose. My opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Use the *W variants of the API functions (GetModuleFileNameW, CopyFileW etc) and use wchar_t characters rather than char throughout.

Your other option would be to take the returned path from SHGetKnownFolderPath and use WideCharToMultiByte to translate the path to chars but the first way is much preferable (it doesn't dpend on the characters matching the user locale for example).